# While converting dataframe to list, integer values are getting converted to long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dataframe to list. The thing is that i don't know which columns has integer values.
(example In this case column 'values' has integer values. columns name could be change)

```py
print df
     name  values
0     red       1
1   green       2
2  yellow       3
res = df.to_dict('records')
print res
```

I expect the output to be:
`[{'values': 1, 'green': nan, 'name': 'red'}, {'values': 2, 'green': '', 'name': nan}, {'values': 3, 'green': nan, 'name': 'yellow'}]`
But the actual output is:
`[{'values': 1L, 'green': nan, 'name': 'red'}, {'values': 2L, 'green': '', 'name': nan}, {'values': 3L, 'green': nan, 'name': 'yellow'}]`

Comment: Note that ``long`` *is* a regular integer as far as Python is concerned and will cleanly interoperate with Python2's ``int`` type. Unless you encounter an actual problem from having a ``long`` instead of an ``int``, the difference is negligible.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi problem is that when i want to store that list in mongo, because mongo is not allowing this.